# What is the meaning/frequency of this Quartz Cron Expression?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

What is the frequency of this value defined in Quartz API?

I have seen the following definition in applicationContext.xml

```
<value>0 * * * * ?</value>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will execute the task **every month**, **every day** at **every hour** at **every minute**, at **second 0**. For example, it will be executed on:

```
21 November 2013, at 17:00:00
21 November 2013, at 17:01:00
21 November 2013, at 17:02:00
```

but it won't be executed on:

```
21 November 2013, at 17:00:01
```

What does the definition in the application.xml mean ?

```
<value>0       *      *         *        *          ?      </value>
       ^       ^      ^         ^        ^          ^
    second  minute   hour  day-of-month  month  day-of-week
```

Note that the `*` sign means **every**, while the `?` character is allowed for the *day-of-month* and *day-of-week* fields. It is used to specify *no specific value*.

More info:

- [Quartz scheduler CronTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06)